# Read YAML from a variable to hash

Tags: perl, yaml

I have a linux command which fetches some data in YAML format from an API. I was looking for a way to populate this variable to a hash array. I was trying `YAML::Tiny`, and the chunk of code that I wrote was:

```
    use YAML::Tiny;
    my $stuff = `unix command that returns as yaml output`
    my $yaml = YAML::Tiny->new;
    $yaml = YAML::Tiny->new->read_string->($stuff);
```

But, running with this code will error out as:

```
    Can't use string ("") as a subroutine ref while "strict refs" in use
```

`$stuff` variable would look like:

```
    Cluster1:
        source_mount: /mnt/uploads
        dir: /a /b
        default: yes
        destination_mount: /var/pub

    Cluster2:
        source_mount: /mnt/uploads
        dir: /c /d /e
        default: no
        destination_mount: /var/pub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not use `new` twice, and there should not be `->` after `read_string` (refer to the POD for [YAML::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?YAML::Tiny)).  Change:

```
$yaml = YAML::Tiny->new->read_string->($stuff);
```

to:

```
$yaml = YAML::Tiny->read_string($stuff);
```

Here is a complete working example:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use YAML::Tiny;

my $stuff = '
    Cluster1:
        source_mount: /mnt/uploads
        dir: /a /b
        default: yes
        destination_mount: /var/pub

    Cluster2:
        source_mount: /mnt/uploads
        dir: /c /d /e
        default: no
        destination_mount: /var/pub
';
my $yaml = YAML::Tiny->new();
$yaml = YAML::Tiny->read_string($stuff);
print $yaml->[0]->{Cluster2}->{dir}, "\n";
```

Output:

```
/c /d /e
```